# Refuting my rav who says that using Mi Yodeya is a bad thing for someone to do?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I seem to be going in circles regarding the use of *Mi Yodeya*. As you can see, I have been a Mi Yodeya member for over a year. I find a lot of good information on it, and, B"H, my profile shows that I've reached approx. 172K people. So, I think that using *Mi Yodeya* has been good for me as well as others whom I may have helped.

My rav is vehemently opposed to using *Mi Yodeya*. He thinks it's extremely harmful and can ruin a person's hashkafa.

I tried to challenge him by citing this verse:

From Ecclesiastes 6:12:

> כִּ֣י מִֽי־יוֹדֵעַ֩ מַה־טּ֨וֹב לָֽאָדָ֜ם בַּֽחַיִּ֗ים

For *Mi Yodeya* is what is good for a man in life

My rav, is still not convinced, even after I show him that someone as wise as the Wise King Solomon knew that *Mi Yodeya* was good for people.

I don't get it. My rabbi dares to challenge the wisdom of King Solomon by adhering to his statement that *Mi Yodeya* causes harm?

Are there any other ideas I can use to convince my rav that using this site is good and not harmful?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Please remember to go to your rabbi for a final ruling.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Mi" knows what is going on. However, no-one else understands the answers on this site. As it says

מִי-הָאִישׁ, הֶחָפֵץ חַיִּים;
אֹהֵב יָמִים, לִרְאוֹת טוֹב.

Mi is the man [known as] the Chofetz Chaim

Thus, we see that only someone on the level of the Chofetz Chaim is able to understand what is going on here and not make mistakes and have his hashkafah weakened.

That is what your Rav is afraid of.

Comment: "Who is this man, the Chofetz Chaim?"

Comment: Mi Yodeah Mi Haish - HeChofetz Chaim m'Radin

Answer (score 3):

According to [the Machberet of Menachem ibn Saruk](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36818&st=&pgnum=56&hilite=) (see the 4st line in Erech "אדם") on the verse, the kamats on the He of Haola is a proof that the verse is not a question but an affirmation.

> מִי יוֹדֵעַ רוּחַ בְּנֵי הָאָדָם הָעֹלָה הִיא לְמָעְלָה וְרוּחַ הַבְּהֵמָה הַיֹּרֶדֶת הִיא לְמַטָּה לָאָרֶץ ‏
> ‏Kohelet 3, 21

So, Mi Yodea elevates the spirit of men, but not of animals.
So if your rav esteems you as a man and not as an animal (Tson Kodashim), he would assume that Mi Yodeya is a benefice for you.